# How can i execute Firefox webdriver in Selenium as Root or superuser

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to execute a python script on Ubuntu server which starts a Firefox webdriver in Selenium.

I need to do it as superuser cause the script starts a VPN and it needs permissions. If i execute the script without superuser permissions it works.

How can i execute this script with permissions?

The execution as superuser pops this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use virtualenv or anaconda?

Comment: No, i'm not using virtualenv or conda.